# How to fix the coredump for 'ProfileInfoCommand' of CLIPS?

Tags: rules, rule-engine, clips, expert-system

CLIPS version: `6.31` .
language: `c++` `clips C API` .

I get a coredump file when execute `ProfileInfoCommand` after `EnvRun`.
Why is this error happening? Is there any usage error here? Or this is a bug?

**The c++ code 1:**

```cpp
#define PROFILING_FUNCTIONS 1

// ...

EnvReset(clips);

// ...
EnvLoadFactsFromString(clips, facts.str().c_str(), -1);
// ...

EnvRun(clips, 100000);
ProfileInfoCommand(clips);
```

I know if `PROFILING_FUNCTIONS` is defined as 1, the `EnvRun` function will start profile automatically.So I use `ProfileInfoCommand` after `EnvRun`,but the coredump has occurred!

And I also tried using another method,but the process also generated a core dump(the same backtrace like `the c++ code 1`).
**The c++ code 2:**

```cpp
EnvReset(clips);
Profile(clips, "constructs");

// ...
EnvLoadFactsFromString(clips, facts.str().c_str(), -1);
// ...

EnvRun(clips, max_iters);
Profile(clips, "off");
ProfileInfoCommand(clips);
```

**The coredump file is following:**

```sh
Core was generated by `/mnt/home/worker/project/ae-arbiter/dist/bin/arbiter-8003 --flagfile=flags.'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000bc6b80 in EnvRtnArgCount (theEnv=Cannot access memory at address 0x7f879c3f6af8
) at /mnt/home/worker/project/ae-arbiter/src/clips/argacces.cc:306
306    for (argPtr = EvaluationData(theEnv)->CurrentExpression->argList;
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000bc6b80 in EnvRtnArgCount (theEnv=0x7f85e6454f70) at /mnt/home/worker/project/ae-arbiter/src/clips/argacces.cc:306
#1  0x0000000000bc6bcd in EnvArgCountCheck (theEnv=0x7f85e6454f70, functionName=0xda1188 "profile", countRelation=2, expectedNumber=1) at /mnt/home/worker/project/ae-arbiter/src/clips/argacces.cc:337
#2  0x0000000000c40803 in ProfileInfoCommand (theEnv=0x7f85e6454f70) at /mnt/home/worker/project/ae-arbiter/src/clips/proflfun.cc:245
#3  0x0000000000b62d12 in arbiter::lib::ClipsModuleExecute (clips=0x7f85e6454f70, features=..., max_iters=100000, result_func=..., module_name=..., halt=@0x7f879c3f6fdc)
    at /mnt/home/worker/project/ae-arbiter/src/lib/clips-utils.cc:357
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting PROFILING_FUNCTIONS to 1 does not automatically profile code when EnvRun is called. It determines whether the profiling functions are included in the CLIPS executable. See Section 2.2 of the [Advanced Programming Guide](http://www.clipsrules.net/apg631.pdf). The functions available for profiling from the CLIPS command are documented in Section 13.15, Profiling Commands, of the [Basic Programming Guide](http://www.clipsrules.net/bpg631.pdf). The ProfileInfoCommand can't be called directly. If you want to call a CLIPS command/function that isn't part of the API described in the Advanced Programming Guide, use the EnvEval API:

```
DATA_OBJECT returnValue;

EnvEval(theEnv,"(profile-info)",&returnValue);
```

Comment: Ok, I understand it wrong. I tried it using the EnvEval API, it works fine. The Clips book is very helpful. Thanks!